# Undefined index $base_path in include(), line 7 of page--front.tpl.php

Tags: 7

I receive this error message in my pages; strange enough, it doesn't appear in the front page.

> Notice: Undefined index: $base_path in include() (line 7 of /home/kinderen/kinderenenislam.nl/sites/all/themes/kei2/page--front.tpl.php).

Where should I include `$base_path`?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something here, but you say you're not receiving the error message in your front page and yet the error message cites 'page--front.tpl.php' as the source of the error (which will be the page template used for the front page). Can you clarify that?

Comment: I created a new theme, probably I'm missing something in my theme. I receive this error message in each page except the **Front page**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$base_path` is a global variable which should definitely be available in your theme's page template files.

I would guess your theme is doing something to remove that var (perhaps in a preprocess function). You can easily solve the problem using one of the following:

1. Using a call to the [`base_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/base_path/7) function instead of `$base_path`.
2. Using `$GLOBALS['base_path'] in place of`$base_path`.
3. Adding the line `<?php global $base_path; ?>` to the top of your page template file(s)

Comment: Thx @Clive, number 1 was my solution